# Vertica - Subquery used as an expression returned more than one row

Tags: vertica

Is it possible to run a query which matches ANY rows in another table column? I'm trying to run this for example:

```html
SELECT *
FROM emails
WHERE address ILIKE '%@' || IN (select * from dictionary.wordlist) || '.%'
```

However this returns [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Subquery used as an expression returned more than one row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that's a strange way of formulating it...

If you go back to a basic SQL tutorial, you will understand that a string literal like `'%@'` , which can be the operand of an ILIKE predicate, cannot be concatenated with an IN () clause - which is a predicate in itself.

I assume that you are looking for all rows in the `emails` table whose address contains any of the words in `dictionary.wordlist` between the at-sign and a dot.

I hope (correct me if I'm wrong) that `dictionary.wordlist` is a table with one column in `VARCHAR()` or other string format. If that is the case, you can go like this:

```
WITH
-- out of "dictionary.wordlist", create an in-line-table containing a column
-- with the wildcard operand to be later used in an ILIKE predicate
operands(operand) AS (
  SELECT
    '%@'||wordlist.word||'.%'
  FROM dictionary.wordlist
)
SELECT
  emails.*
FROM emails
INNER JOIN operands
ON email.address ILIKE operands.operand
;
```

There are other ways of doing it, of course, but this is one of them.
I'm not trying to say it will be very fast - an ILIKE predicate as a JOIN condition can't be performant ...

Good luck

Marco the Sane